# Grabbing values between nested quotation marks and replacing it enclosed inside some command

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

In my previous post, I learned how to text enclosed in quotation marks,  `"Sample text"`, and replace it with `\command{Sample text}` via regex.

```
Search: "(.*?)"
Replace: \\command{$1}
```

How do I do it when there are nested quotation marks. For example:

```
"This quote which involves "inner quotes," and possibly even more nested quotes."
```

To:

```
\command{This quote which involves \command{inner quotes,} and possibly even more nested quotes.}
```

(I usually work in notepad++.)

Comment: It seems to be it is not possible to write a regex that will work with just one hit of *Replace all* button (as the texts are overlapping). You can only use `"((?>[^"\n]+|(?R))*)"` (remove `\n` if the quoted substrings span across multiple lines) and replace with `\\command{$1}` and hit *Replace all* until you see no more occurrences are replaced.

Comment: @stribizhev I think your suggestion does not really decrease the amount of work. If what I am asking for is impossible, then I have to content with the original approach and try search and replace manually, case by case.